# mysql - function not executing

Tags: mysql

Below function is not executing ..i dnt know why..

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `vcbvb`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`dffgdfgfdgg`@`%` FUNCTION `split_string`(
stringToSplit VARCHAR(256),
SIGN VARCHAR(12),
POSITION INT
)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(256);


BEGIN

RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringToSplit, SIGN, POSITION),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringToSplit, SIGN, POSITION -1)) + 1), SIGN, '');

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Please help me i am getting the error as below

**Error :**
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';

```
BEGIN

RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringToSplit,' at line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `vcbvb`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`dffgdfgfdgg`@`%` FUNCTION `split_string`(
stringToSplit VARCHAR(256),
SIGN VARCHAR(12),
POSITION INT
)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(256);


BEGIN

RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringToSplit, SIGN, POSITION),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(stringToSplit, SIGN, POSITION -1)) + 1), SIGN, ``);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> I think you have to change the quotes from '' to ``